# Почему action creater вызывается 2 раза по клику на кнопку?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from '../Header/Header.js';
import Filter from '../Generals/Filter/Filter';
import history from '../Router/History';
import { setMainFilterDevice, setMainFilterProvider } from '../../actions/Actions';


class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header caption='test' buttons={
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Добавить",
                            func: () => {history.push("/newmarket")},
                            classes: "btn-success ml-3"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Удалить все",
                            func: () => {this.props.changeFilterProvider(3)},
                            classes: "btn-danger ml-3"
                        }
                    ]
                }/> 
                <Filter
                   caption="Тип устройства:"
                   float="right"
                   direction="row" 
                   buttons={
                    [
                        {
                            text: "Desktop",
                            value: 0,
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Tablet",
                            value: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Mobile",
                            value: 2,
                        }
                    ]        
                  }
                  activeValue={this.props.filterDevice}
                  onChangeVal={ (val) => this.props.changeFilterDevice.bind(this, val) }
                />
                <Filter
                   caption="Поставщик:" 
                   float="right"
                   direction="row" 
                   buttons={
                    [
                        {
                            text: "111",
                            value: 0,
                        },
                        {
                            text: "222",
                            value: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            text: "333",
                            value: 2,
                        }
                    ]        
                  }
                  activeValue={this.props.filterProvider}
                  onChangeVal = { (val) => this.props.changeFilterProvider.bind(this, val) }
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        filterDevice: state.Main.filterDevice,
        filterProvider: state.Main.filterProvider,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
        changeFilterDevice : (val) => {
            dispatch(setMainFilterDevice(val))
        },
        changeFilterProvider : (val) => {
            dispatch(setMainFilterProvider(val))
        }
    }
};


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

Filter.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Filter = ({caption, buttons, onChangeVal, activeValue, float, direction}) => 
    <div className={"d-flex align-items-center mt-2 mb-2" + getClassElem("container", float, direction)}>
       { caption ? 
            <div className={"mr-3" + getClassElem("caption", null, direction)}><strong>{caption}</strong></div>
        :
        ""
       }

        <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle ">
            {
               buttons.map((btn, i) => 
                   <label className={"btn btn-secondary" + (activeValue === btn.value ? " active" : "")} onClick={onChangeVal(btn.value)} key={i}>
                        <input type="radio" name="options"  autoComplete="off" defaultChecked="" value={btn.value}/> {btn.text}
                    </label>
               ) 
            }
        </div>
   </div>

export default Filter;

const getClassElem = (type, float, direction) => {
    let className = "";
    switch(type){
        case "container":
            switch(float){
                case "left":
                    className += " mr-auto";
                    break;
                case "right":
                    className += " ml-auto";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            switch(direction){
                case "column":
                    className += " flex-column";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "caption":
            switch(direction){
                case "column":
                    className += " mb-2";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break; 
        default: 
            break; 
    }
    return className;
}
```

По клику на label вызывается функция, которую я передал в качестве параметра из Main.js. Эта функция в свою очередь диспатчит action. В консоли action отрабатывает два раза по клику. Не пойму в чем может быть дело. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы вешаете на onClick не функцию, а результат её выполнения. Вам надо вместо вот этого `onClick={onChangeVal(btn.value)}` написать вот так: `onClick={onChangeVal.bind(thid, btn.value)}`

Comment: onChangeVal={ (val) => this.props.changeFilterDevice.bind(this, val) } 
я в свойство уже передаю функцию с оберткой (bind)

Comment: Вы не правильно вызываете функцию в компоненте Filter. Замените на `() => onChangeVal(btn.value)`